# fprintf is not printing to the file

Tags: c, file-io, printf

In following code the fprintf is not printing to the file and printf is showing wrong output:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void main()
{  
    FILE *fp;  
    int d,w,t;
    fp = fopen("file.txt","r+");//already created file having value 10
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&d); 
    printf("%d",d);//print value 10
    t=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,t,SEEK_END);
    fprintf(fp,"%d",1000); // printing 1000 to the file
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&w);
    printf("%d",w); // this printf is still printing wrong value 12803
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: your code works for me, on GCC, GNU/Linux

Comment: I think you need to initialize d and w to 0

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings. Also _check the return values of all system calls_!

Comment: @Mat: and the return value of library functions.

Comment: Are you expecting to read the value of 1000 after you write it?  You would need to use `ftell` and `fseek` to back up after writing, because writing will move the file pointer as well.

Comment: `printf("%d",&d);` does NOT `//print value 10`, but its address.

Comment: Don't tell us it's "showing the wrong output" without showing us the output. And `void main()` is wrong; use `int main(void)`.

Comment: Ok, I see you've shown us the wrong output in a comment in the source code. It's better to show that separately; embedded comments are too easy to miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform an `fseek()` (or similar) between reads and writes in the same file.  It's not a strict requirement in all implementations, but it's necessary for portability.

---

**EDIT**

OK, your new verison has:

```
t=ftell(fp);
fseek(fp,t,SEEK_END);
```

which might make sense in some instances, but probably not this one.  I
think you meant:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

which seeks relative to the current position, without actually moving
anywhere.

But the reason you're not getting `w==1000` is between these two lines:

```
fprintf(fp,"%d",1000); // printing 1000 to the file
fscanf(fp,"%d",&w);
```

You transition from writing to reading without a seek here.  You can't
be altogether sure where in the file you're going to try to read `w`
from without using a seek to re-assert the position you intend.

Try:

```
t = ftell(fp);
fprintf(fp,"%d",1000); // printing 1000 to the file
fseek(fp, t, SEEK_SET);
fscanf(fp,"%d",&w);
```

There are a bunch of other hazards around this code, by the way; like
that the `fprintf` doesn't print any terminating character, so there
might be trailing digits after where you've written (from previous
writes of other values, or whatever) which get appended to the value
read into `w`.

Comment: I use fseek() but still the printf() statement is printing the value 12803

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void main()
```

This is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`. If you have a book that
tells you to use `void main()`, its author doesn't know C very well;
get a better book.

```
{
    FILE *fp;
    int d,w,t;
    fp = fopen("file.txt","r+");//already created file having value 10
```

You need to check whether the `fopen` call succeeded or not, and
probably terminate the program if it failed.

```
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&d);
    printf("%d",d);//print value 10
```

Assuming everything went well so far, this will print `10` *without a newline*.
If your program worked, its output would be `101000`.  Change "%d" to "%d\n".

```
    t=ftell(fp);
```

`t` is the current position in the file, which should be just after
the `10`, so it's 2 bytes from the beginning.

```
    fseek(fp,t,SEEK_END);
```

Now you reposition the file pointer to 2 bytes *before the end of
the file*.  That doesn't make any sense.  Where you end up relative
to the "10" depends on what else is in `file.txt` (newline? CR-LF?)

You can save the value returned by `ftell()` and use it later in a
call to `fseek`, but that only makes sense if the third argument is
`SEEK_SET`.  So you probably want:

```
t = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, t, SEEK_SET);
```

That doesn't change your position in the file, but it does allow you
to read from a file that you've been writing to.

Oh, and `ftell` and `fseek` work with `long` values, not `int`.
Your program (with these fixes) is likely to work if the file isn't
too big, but you really should declare `t` as `long` variable.

I also suggest that using names like `d`, `w`, and `t` make your code more difficult to read. Use longer descriptive names. Think about someone other than you trying to read and understand your code -- or you reading your own code a month from now, when you've forgotten what `d` is.

With these changes, your current position in `file.txt should now be
just after the`10`.

```
    fprintf(fp,"%d",1000); // printing 1000 to the file
```

And now you print `1000` immediately after the `10`, so now the file
contains `101000`, and your current position is *after* the last
character you wrote.

```
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&w);
```

Here you try to read from the file immediately after writng to it.
But you're at the end of the file, so there's nothing to read.
Since you didn't check the result of `fscanf` (which would have told you
it failed), `w` is unchanged,

```
    printf("%d",w); // this printf is still printing wrong value 12803
```

Again, adding a newline would make the output much easier to read.

```
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
```

`getch()` is a Windows-specific (and MSDOS-specific) function that
waits for user input before terminating your program.  If you insist
on using it, you need, if I recall correctly, `#include <windows.h>`.
You should turn up your compiler's warning levels if it didn't complain
about a missing declaration for `getch`.

```
}
```

Summary:

If you want to read and write to the same open file, you can do that
-- but you need to call some positioning function such as `fseek`
between reading and writing, or between writing and reading.

You should check the values returned by all library calls.  For
example, if `file.txt` doesn't exist, your program quietly ignores
the error and continues to try to read and write to the file, with
undefined results.  (It's common to ignore the result of a `printf`
call, since there's not a lot you can do if printing to standard
output fails, but it's instructive to look at the result anyway.)

Write your `printf` calls so the output is readable.  Print newline
(`\n`) at the end of each output lines.

Read the documentation for each function you use.

Ask your compiler to warn you about questionable constructs.  See your
compiler's documentation to find out how to do this.